# PostgreSQL no relations found

Tags: postgresql

I am running ruby and rails app with postgresql database, and I want to do batch import from text file to the database.

I've configured the database and if I run `psql` and `\l` to list all databases, I can see it.

However, after I run `rake db:migrate` no relations are created in the database and running `psql``\d` in order to check tables, says "No relations found". But the schema is created and I can see the tables in Induction PostgreSQL client (http://inductionapp.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem may be a namespace issue.  You can `\dn` to list namespaces.

Keep in mind that by default `\d` only lists relations in the search path, and you can run `show search_path` to see what this is.

If you want to list relations in a namespace outside the search path, \d mynamespace.* will list them and their attributes.  You can also:

```
set search_path = 'mynamespace';
\d
set search_path = 'public';
```

To temporarily change the search path for purposes of using \d

Comment: "namespace" is synonymous with "schema" in this case.